# Contacts search on New Outlook on MacOS contact lost

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, search, autocomplete, contacts

When you compose a new email in the "New Outlook" UX on MacOS, in the "to" field I was finding a contact via autocomplete by typing the first few letters of their email and she would show up. I have accidentally clicked on the small "x" on the right of the autocomplete item, and now that contact will never show up when doing a search!

I can, however, go to the "Contacts" window and search for that contact from there and she will show up. So now whenever I want to email this person I have to do it this way and it is quite annoying.

I have tried deleting the Gmail account from Outlook locally, uninstalling and reinstalling Outlook (all data is restored), but none if this solves my issue!

How can I do a reset on that "to" field's autocomplete options?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restore this location: \Users<username>\Library\Group Containers\UBF8T346G9.Office\Outlook\Outlook 15 Profiles<Profiles name>\Data\Recent Addresses

Besides, I have also found a related tools:[Mac Outlook Cached Contacts Recovery](https://macwaretools.com/recovery/outlook-cached-contacts.html), it's suggested to check if it could also work for you.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved? Would you mind sharing your update or marking the helpful post to answer?